# How can I set view permissions for content type to make it visible to autenticated users only?

Tags: nodes, authentication-authorization, 10

I want a content type to be only visible to authenticated users.

Now the edit permission dialog only offers permissions for modification, not for displaying the published content.

Until Drupal 9, I've used the *Permissions by Term* module to limit public access for certain page areas and content types. Since *Permissions by Term* is not yet Drupal 10 compatible I had to remove it.

Is there an elegant, ideally Drupal 10 native way, to limit certain content types from public access?

> [image: Edit permission dialog for content type]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal core doesn't come with the separate "View content" permission.

To get that functionality you need to search for a module that adds it.

I think all the contributed modules that provide additional permissions, at least the ones I've tried, can be described as "Drupal native" because they tie into Drupal permissions system, they don't bypass it.

[Permissions by Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term) is a great module, although it is an overkill if you have clean permission separation based on Content Type, and you don't need fine-grained control of individual nodes within a Content Type. You can use a content-type-based permissions module instead:

I've tried [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) in the past and I was happy with it. You should search the modules list to investigate all that are available and pick according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see my question: I had used _Permissions by Term_ until the Drupal 10 migration. Unfortunately this module is not Drupal 10 compatible yet. That's the source of my question. As you write, I agree it's also overkill, for an basic functionality which should be part of Drupal itself. I've also checked _Content Access_, but this module does not even have a stable Drupal 9 release. IMO the Drupal module ecosystem feels a bit broken, since even basic requirements are not covered. I'll keep on researching. :-)

Comment: These requirements might seem basic to you but they aren't necessary in lot many cases, so it makes sense not to have that functionality bloat Drupal core. You can always contribute and get the modules you need get to newer versions faster. FOSS projects don't mean contributions have to be volunteered. Maybe you can find a programmer to do the work for a small bounty if you can't program yourself.

Comment: Content Access Module available at https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access
is the way to go for me.

Comment: one year later i'm back on that topic : ) now i decided to use "Content Access". Even though there is still only a `dev` branch available, it seems to fulfill my needs. Thanks and accepting your answer.